# ¿Cómo acceder al valor de un elemento con useRef en react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

¿Cómo se accede al valor de un elemento usando `useRef`?

Quiero algo como el `target` que me regresaban los eventos, en el cual podía acceder a todo, incluyendo al `target.value`, pero usando `ref` con `useRef`, solo puedo ingresar al `classList` y id, pero no al `value`, ¿hay alguna manera?

Comment: agrega el código

Answer (score 1):

podrias hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
  function App() {
      const inputRef= useRef();

  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { value, name } = e;
    console.log(name); // obteniendo el name attr del input desde el evento
    console.log(value); // obteniendo el valor del input desde el evento

    console.log(inputRef.current.value); // obteniendo el valor del input desde el ref
    console.log(inputRef.curren.name); // obteniendo el name attr del input desde el ref

  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input 
          ref={inputRef} 
          type="text" 
          name="name" 
          value={value} 
          onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

el evento se sigue pasando a la funcion handler de tu input o lo que estes usando, entoces podrias usarlo tambien, pero si tienes algun caso especial por el cual no lo puedas usar, entonces esa es la manera de hacerlo como esta en el ejemplo que puse.

Comment: Pero, entonces no hay una opcion ya establecida por useRef para acceder al texto dentro de las etiquetas del componente al cual le puse el ref?

Answer (score 1):

Usando React Hooks puedes [crear refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) usando `useRef`, el mismo habilita una propiedad `current` el cual te da acceso a los atributos del elemento al que hace referencia:

Primero definimos la referencia vacía:

```
const inputRef = React.useRef(null);
```

Luego, se la asignamos al elemento en cuestión:

```
<input type="text=" ref={inputRef} />
```

Ejemplo:

```js
function App() {
  // Definimos una referencia vacia
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    // `current` apunta al elemento input en cuestion
    console.log('El value de input es: ', inputRef.current.value)
  };

    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          Nombre:
          <input type="text=" placeholder="Felix" ref={inputRef} />
        </label>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Enviar</button>
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```